Account incorrectly showing as disabled in password change dialog
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 in a VirtualBox VM. I would like to change my password but the password change GUI says "Account disabled" next to the Password option:

I can still click into the Password change option and enter the old and new password, but the Change button is greyed out and cannot be clicked:

Note that to be able to click into that change dialog, I had to initially click Unlock on the blue notice at the top of the main dialog and enter my existing password:

From looking through other similar questions, it seems like most ppl see this issue when either a) their account never had a password set, b) their account really is disabled, or c) their account does not have permission to change its own password (like, it need to be done by an admin).
In my case, my account definitely has a password and definitely is not disabled, or at least not completely. I can lock the screen and login with the existing password. And if I try to login with a blank password that does not work.
I'm not sure about the account admin level stuff.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue? And also, what does Account disabled mean in this context since for me it's not indicating I can't log in. Does that have some more specific meaning in this context? I feel like this could be clearer in the GUI.
Thanks.


Does your account have sudo access? For example, can you run sudo apt update?

Yes, I can run sudo apt update. When I do so, I am prompted for my account's password, and after I enter that it appears to run fine (I get a summary at the end telling me how many packages can be upgraded).

It seems that you are not the system administrator, but still have sudo access, so you can use the command line to change your password. See my answer below

Since you have sudo access, you can use command line to change your password.
Run the following command (replace username with the actual username), and it will ask you to enter your new password.
sudo passwd username


This worked. Thanks for the help!
